# How to make the background not wrap around the paragraph tag

Tags: html, css

For my new website, I’m trying to make the background stay as the background, and to make the paragraph tag sit by itself. I don’t want for the background to make different rectangles with the background inside them, I want the background to be one whole thing. Here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=decice-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kulim+Park&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <title>zippernet</title>
        <style>
            body {
                background: rgb(2,0,36);
background: linear-gradient(10deg, rgba(2,0,36,1) 0%, rgba(80,80,255,1) 100%, rgba(0,212,255,1) 100%);
            }
            p, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
                font-family: 'Kulim Park', sans-serif; 
                color: white;
            }
            .rotated-heading {
                font-size: 50px;
                float: right;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p class="rotated-heading">Welcome to zippernet!</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here’s the website URL: https://zippernet.000webhostapp.com/index.html

Comment: Note: I’m willing to keep the “Welcome to zippernet!” on the right side of the screen.

Comment: From what I understand based on your question, you want the gradient effect to take up the whole page, you can use 90deg as your angle instead of 10deg. Not sure if that's the effect you're after.

Comment: That could work, but I would like to keep the gradient.

Comment: I wonder if `decice-width` is a typo - should be `device-width`?

Comment: @halfer thanks for the comment! I’m no longer working on this project, so it shouldn’t matter.

Comment: Fair enough, and it may not have mattered for this problem anyway. That said, I offer the advice that on Stack Overflow, we try to maintain questions and answers for the benefit of future readers, rather than for whatever initial purpose they were asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I interpret your question to mean that you want the gradient to cover the full width and height of the browser window. If that is correct, the following CSS should help you solve your problem.

```
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  height: 100%;
  background: rgb(2,0,36);
  background: linear-gradient(10deg, rgba(2,0,36,1) 0%, rgba(80,80,255,1) 100%, rgba(0,212,255,1) 100%);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
p, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    font-family: 'Kulim Park', sans-serif;
    color: white;
}
.rotated-heading {
    font-size: 50px;
    float: right;
}
```